# If $T: P_1 \rightarrow P_1$ is a linear transformation...

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T: P_1 \rightarrow P_1$ is a linear transformation such that
$T(1+5 x) = 3 + 3 x$  and  $T(4 + 19 x) = -1 + 3 x$, then
$T(-2 - 4 x) =$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Write $-2-4x$ as a linear combination of $1+5x$ and $4+19x$ by setting $-2-4x = a(1+5x)+b(4+19x)$ and solving for $a$ and $b$ be equating coefficients of powers of $x.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First use $(4 + 19x) - 4(1 + 5x)$ to figure out where $T$ maps $x$.